# Contar linhas laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Bom estou utilizando `Laravel 5.2` e tenho muita duvida para contar as linhas referente a minha pesquisa. Preciso retornar o numero de produtos dentro de `Categorias` e `SubCategorias`.

Meus relacionamento estão da seguinte forma, na tabela Produto tenho um campo CdSubCategoria que faz referencia ao CdSubCategoria da tabela de SubCategoria, além disto tenho dentro da tabela de SubCategoria o código da categoria, isto devido ao relacionamento (um para muitos em relação categoria e subcategoria) como na imagens a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em meu model Produto fiz assim:

```
class Produto extends Model
{
 use SoftDeletes;

 protected $fillable = [
    'CdSubCategoria',
    'NmProduto',
    'DscProduto',
    'VlUnit',
    'UnitEmEstoque',
    'FlgDescontinuado',
    'FlgProdutoVisivel',
    'Visivel_Ini',
    'Visivel_Fim',
    'FlgPontua',
    'QtdPontos',
    'MaxPontosPorSubCategoria'
];
protected $primaryKey = 'CdProduto';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function subCategoria()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategoria','CdSubCategoria','CdSubCategoria');
}

public function imagens(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Imagem', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
}

public function lotes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\LoteProduto', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
}

public function tipo_produto_embalagem(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoProdutoEmbalagem', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
 }
}
```

Ja no model Categoria:

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
 use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['NmCategoria', 'DscCategoria'];
protected $primaryKey = 'CdCategoria';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function subCategorias()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategoria','CdCategoria','CdCategoria');
 }
}
```

E por fim no model SubCategoria:

```
class SubCategoria extends Model
{
 use SoftDeletes;

 protected $fillable = ['CdCategoria','NmSubCategoria', 'DscSubCategoria', 'FlgPontua', 'QtdPontos', 'MaxPontosCategoria'];
 protected $primaryKey = 'CdSubCategoria';
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

 public function categoria()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','CdCategoria','CdCategoria');
 }

 public function produtos(){
    return  $this->hasMany('App\Produto','CdSubCategoria','CdSubCategoria');
 }
}
```

Contar o numero de produtos dentro de uma subcategoria eu consegui de forma estática, e fiz da seguinte forma:

```
 $count = Produto::where('CdSubCategoria','3')->count();
 dd($count);
```

Porém tenho alguns problemas como:

1. Preciso conta todas as `subCategorias`, ou seja esta contagem precisa ser dinâmica. Vale lembrar que preciso desta informação em minha view, pois la estou utilizando assim:

   NOME DA CATEGORIA (QTD PRODUTO)
2. Preciso além de conta a quantidade de produtos por `subCategoria` é necessário produto por categorias (Lembrando que este relacionamento é um para muitos)

**OBS.**

> O ideal é que esta informação venha juntamente com meu model. Ex: da mesma forma que eu acesso `$produto->imagens` poderia acessar `$subCategoria->qtd` e `$categoria->qtd`

Comment: o item **1)** Nome e SubCategoria são da tabela produtos?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não, como mostrado na imagem Produto so tem CdSubCategoria, ja dentro de SubCategoria tenho nome dela e ainda o CdCategoria.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Atualizei minha pergunta, verifica se agora está entendível ?

Comment: você colocou dois códigos da Categoria pode adicionar o da sub-categoria?

Comment: Perdão ja atualizei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Preciso conta todas as subCategorias, ou seja esta contagem precisa ser dinâmica. Vale lembrar que preciso desta informação em minha view, pois la estou utilizando assim: ***NOME DA CATEGORIA (QTD PRODUTO)***

O [***withCount***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) para que dê corretamente no seu caso tem que ser de `SubCategoria` para `Produto`:

```
$s = new SubCategoria();
$r = $s->withCount("produtos")->get();
var_dump($r);
```

o retorno vai mostrar algo:

```
[
    {
        "CdSubCategoria": 1,
        "CdCategoria": 1,
        "NmSubCategoria": "Sub Categoria 1",
        "DscSubCategoria": "Sub Categoria 1",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "produtos_count": 2
    },
    {
        "CdSubCategoria": 2,
        "CdCategoria": 1,
        "NmSubCategoria": "Sub Categoria 2",
        "DscSubCategoria": "Sub Categoria 2",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "produtos_count": 1
    },
    {
        "CdSubCategoria": 3,
        "CdCategoria": 2,
        "NmSubCategoria": "Sub Categoria 3",
        "DscSubCategoria": "Sub Categoria 3",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "produtos_count": 1
    }
]
```

---

> 2) Preciso além de conta a quantidade de produtos por subCategoria é necessário produto por categorias (Lembrando que este relacionamento é um para muitos)

```
$c = new Categoria();
$r = $c
     ->join('sub_categorias','sub_categorias.CdCategoria','=','categoria.CdCategoria')
     ->join('produtos','produtos.CdSubCategoria','=','sub_categorias.CdSubCategoria')
     ->selectRaw('categoria.CdCategoria,categoria.NmCategoria, count(*) count_produto_cat')
     ->groupBy(['categoria.CdCategoria','categoria.NmCategoria'])
     ->get();
```

o retorno vai mostrar algo:

```
[
    {
        "CdCategoria": 1,
        "NmCategoria": "Categoria 1 ",
        "count_produto_cat": 3
    },
    {
        "CdCategoria": 2,
        "NmCategoria": "Categoria 2",
        "count_produto_cat": 1
    }
]
```

**Observação:** Vale lembrar que `Produtos` não tem relação direta com `Categoria`

Comment: Ele retorna o numero de produtos ? No caso de produtos que tenho tal categoria ?

Comment: Sim ele retorna `produtos_count`, e `Produtos` não tem relação com `Categoria`.! ele tem relação com `Subcategorias` ou estou enganado?

Comment: Eh Categoria relaciona sub categoria, na verdade o que precisa ser feito é somar quantos produtos existem dentro de subCategorias, pois a relação é produto subcategoria

Comment: @RenanRodrigues esta editado a resposta e testado inclusive! `SubCategorias` que é o primeiro exemplo de código traz a quantidade de `Produtos` na `produtos_count`.

Comment: Seu ultimo código esta contando o numero de subcategorias preciso que conte produtos. A pergunta que preciso responder é, Quantos produtos existem em tal categoria.

Comment: Agora foi editado e a única forma seria com `join` e agrupamento aonde ele vai imprimir as categorias e a quantidade de produtos por categoria

Comment: Você é simplesmente de mais, não sabia que teria oportunidade de fazer joins. obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você está querendo dá pra fazer com `withCount`. Esse método você usa para poder trazer a contagem dos relacionamentos.

Veja:

```
$produtos = Produto::with('imagens')->withCount('imagens')->where(['created_at' => new DateTime])->get();
```

Para você poder acessar o valor da contagem, basta adicionar `_count` na frente do nome do relacionamento:

```
 $produto->imagens_count; // 3
```

Comment: Vou testar, e posto aqui